# The support function of two sets are equal iff the sets are equal

Tags: convex-analysis

I am not sure how to approach this question from Boyd.

> How to show that the support function of two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $A=B$.
>
> The support function for a set $A$ is defined as $S_A(x)=\sup\limits_{y \in A}\langle x,y\rangle$.

For more information on support function go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235926/what-is-a-support-function-sup-z-in-k-langle-z-x-rangle)

Comment: I'm not sure where the question is in this post.

Comment: @Arkamis Sorry about that. I have updated the question.

Comment: What does $\sup$ mean, and what is $\langle x, y\rangle$?

Comment: @TaraB http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235926/what-is-a-support-function-sup-z-in-k-langle-z-x-rangle . sup means supremum.

Comment: OK, so $A$ and $B$ aren't just sets, but ordered sets.  How about my other question?

Comment: @TaraB Thats the inner product $x^Ty$

Comment: Oh, so they're not just ordered sets, but sets with an inner product defined on them!  You know you should really state these assumptions, right?

Comment: @TaraB Sorry I thought that was obvious. The link I provided explains them in detail.

Comment: No, it is not obvious.  If you just say 'set', it means a set with no extra structure.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed statement is false.  For a counterexample, in the plane, take $A$ to be the unit disk (centered at the origin) and take $B$ to be its boundary, the unit circle.  Both have the support function $x\mapsto\Vert x\Vert$.  The interior of the disk also has the same support function, as do lots of other sets.

The statement becomes true if you add the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are compact convex sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to approach this taking the assumption you mentioned.